How are ancilla qubits physically prepared and measured?
As I understand the general procedure of quantum computing:

We prepare our quantum states depending on what calculation we want to do (ex: creating a spin superposition of entangled states by driving a system of qubits in an oriented magnetic field)
We perform unitary transformations in a specified order (our quantum algorithm) on the superposition. These are by definition reversible operations. During the running of the algorithm we perform error corrections. We perform additional adjustment operations on the qubits based on the error correction results. This may or may not involve ancilla qubits.
After our algorithm of unitary transformations is complete we measure the state (whether its by measuring the spin, or a teleportation measurement, etc) which results in a 1 or 0 classical bit that is the collapsed state. These 1 or 0 states follow the probability distributions given by the wave function superpositions at the end of the algorithm. This is by definition not reversible.

In general if we entangle and measure the ancilla state also with spin states during the computation, our computation is botched because our superposition is lost by measuring the ancilla. Thus our ancilla must be entangled in a manner that doesn't disturb the original qubits.
What properties do we usually prepare and measure the ancilla qubits with? How is this done physically?
Specifically, in qubits that utilize spin superpositions. Let's say the operational qubits are entangled with a linear combination of spin $S_{\pm}=S_{x}\pm iS_{y}$. What is the most common observable used in practice? For example, would our ancilla qubits be entangled to the operational qubits via $S^{2}$ since the commutator is 0?

You should have edited your other question, rather than deleting it and posting this one. (This also has practically relevant consequences: Deleted questions count against you in the system.)

Oh I see. I will remember that next time. Thank you for letting me know!

If you’re using ancilla registers for intermediate operations, the common practice is to perform uncomputation; i.e., perform the operations that entangled the ancilla register to the main registers but in reverse to “disentangle” them

I don't know if I fully understand the question, but ancillary qubits are not fundamentally different from the other qubits. You prepare them like you do for the rest. What that means physically totally  depends on the physical embodiment of the qubits

Is there some possibilities to innovate in this? Like ancillary qubits with lower coherence time. Does that type of system make any sense in some cases?

I think you should differentiate between the abstract operations and the hardware implementation. I don't know about the latter, but regarding the former:
Measuring an ancilla qubit doesn't ruin all of the superposition, it just projects the state into a specific subspace, depending on the outcome. The easiest way to think about it for me is by consider stabilizer codes. There, you can take an ancilla qubit, entangle it to the circuit, and its measurement result gives you the parity of some of the qubits. This parity does not collapse the state (i.e. if ZZ = 1, you can still be in a superposition of, e.g. $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$), but rather projects it to a specific subspace.
